# Get dimension of a list

Tags: code-golf, counting

Find out the dimension of a simple nested list:

```
[] -> 1
[[]] -> 2
[[[]]] -> 3
...
```

List taken as input, dimension as output.
No counting length of strings - list manipulation and loops only.
i.e. no getting the length of the input and dividing by 2.

Any language is permitted. Get golfing!

Comment: Isn't it just counting the number of `[`?

Comment: Good idea, but that is a loophole, so I will make that illegal. @MorganThrapp

Comment: @WheatWizard I'd say no, only because this doesn't actually require any parsing. Now, it's probably going to end up being a dupe of that, but it's not currently.

Comment: Okay, so I'll count the number of `]`. Or divide the length of the input by 2. This challenge in its current state is trivial. The [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is a great place to get input on your challenges before posting them.

Comment: Read about [patching out approaches](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8943/20260).

Comment: avoid [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/46756). In Python the `len()` function works for list so I could claim `print len(raw_input())/2` is list manipulation, not string counting.

Comment: Is my 1 byte Retina answer as valid as the Jelly one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒḊ
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLhuIo&input=&args=W1tbW11dXV0)**

It's a single atom, the depth monad.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, <s>2</s> 1 byte<s>s</s>

```
]
```

Just Regex.

One byte to Martin Ender.

Comment: `]` saves a byte.

Comment: Invalid since the last edit

Answer (score 1):

## Brain-Flak, <s>44</s> <s>36</s> <s>32</s> 26 + 3 = 29 bytes

[Try it online](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdKSh7PCh7fVsoKSgpXSk-KCl9e308Pik&input=W1tbW11dXV0&args=LWE&debug=on)

```
([])({<({}[()()])>()}{}<>)
```

+3 bytes from the `-a` flag.

### Explanation

```
([])                         #Push the stack height
     {<({}[()()])>()}{}      #For loop decrement by 2
    (                  <>)   #Push number of runs to the offstack
```